# Cant change display style

Tags: html, css

I have two div forms,and want to switch from the one to another by style.display,but it doesn't work.
Code:

**JavaScript**

```
  function switchForm(){


      var x = document.getElementById("register")

      if(x.style.display === "none"){


    x.style.display ==="initialize";
  }

else{
  x.style.display === "none";
}
```

}

**HTML**

Register

Comment: Welcome! what is `initialize` in your `<script>`,i did not get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign values to a variable you need to use one equals sign (`=`) and not three.  Here is your fixed code:

```
function switchForm(){

  var x = document.getElementById("register")

  if(x.style.display === "none"){

    x.style.display = "initialize";

  } else {

    x.style.display = "none";

  }
}
```

You will also have to assign the other variable:

```
function switchForm(){

  var x = document.getElementById("register")
  var y = document.getElementById("myOtherForm")

  if(x.style.display === "none"){

    x.style.display = "initialize";
    y.style.display = "none";

  } else {

    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "initialize";

  }
}
```

Comment: If it helped you, mark this answer as accepted so other people will know your question is solved. (Click the big green checkmark)